# Multithreading on python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

```
import threading
import time

x = 1

# First thread. We pass in one parameter
def thread1(param):
    global x
    while True:
        x = x + 1
        print("This is thread 1. x is %d" % x)
        time.sleep(param)

# Second thread. We pass in two parameters
def thread2(param1, param2):
    global x
    while True:
        x = x * 2
        print("This is thread 2. Param 2 is %d. x is %d" % (param2, x))
        time.sleep(param1)

# Create the first thread
th1 = threading.Thread(target = thread1, args = [1, ])
th1.start()
th2 = threading.Thread(target = thread2, args =  [2, 123])
th2.start()
```

The above code produces the following output:

[image: Output]

Why is the “thread1” thread incrementing it one once per second, and “thread2” doubles x every 2 seconds.

Comment: Is that not exactly what you coded? You passed `param1=1` to thread1, and `param1=2` to thread2. And in both thread, `param1` is the amount of second to wait between two iterations. So, what else were you expecting? It would be easier to understand your question knowing what behavior was expected.

Comment: Also, please, [avoid posting images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) :-)